# Overload function call operator () in struct / what happens to arguments?

Tags: c++

Hi there and many thanks in advance!

I'm using `std::unique` to `erase` from a `std::vector`. To check the uniqueness I'm calling a boolean function of a struct. Because I'd like to use a predefined tolerance, I tried to add a constructor to which the desired value is passed. It works, but I don't really know why.

```
std::vector<std::pair<int,double> > myVec;

struct Check{

  double tol_ = 0.0;
  Check(double tol) : tol_(tol)
  {        
  }

  bool operator()(const std::pair<int,double> &a, 
                  const std::pair<int,double> &b)
  {
    return fabs(a.second-b.second) < tol_;
  }
};

// fill vector
...

// remove duplicates
myVec.erase(std::unique(myVec.begin(), myVec.end(), Check(0.1)), myVec.end());
```

Is this in someway reasonable practice? I'm kind of confused about the `unique`. When this function is reached, the struct `Check` is constructed using the tolerance. 
Next `unique` calls this struct a few more times to compare the vector elements by passing them as a reference?

Thanks for your efforts!

Comment: Why are you doing `myVec->begin()` instead of `myVec.begin()` ?

Comment: First of all [`std::unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) removes duplicate *consecutive* elements. That means your range must be sorted. Secondly, `myVec` doesn't seem to be a pointer, using the arrow member access operator is wrong. Lastly, *how* does it not work? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Do you have any real question? I mean I can only answer with "yes". this is reasonable practice and done that way. So you are right how this works.

Comment: The answer is yes. And you can see the possible implementation of unique at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique for more details.

Comment: @PRP: Yeah, the _arrow operator_ is wrong here, i got that out of a function and forgot to adapt this.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Thanks for the hint, i forgot to mention that i sort the elements first.

Comment: If your question is about understanding functors, you should probably leave the whole `std:unique` part out of it.

Comment: Thanks to all, obviously it is possible and good practice?
I know how to use `unique`, but I was wondering how it works together with the call of the contructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens when you do `Check(0.1)` in the call to `std::unique` is that a temporary object is created. This temporary object will have a lifetime to the end of the full expression.

The temporary object is passed like any other object to the `std::unique` function. This works because that argument is a templated argument and can have any type matching the usage of it.

In short the call to `std::unique` is roughly equivalent to something like this:

```
// Enter new nested local scope
{
    Check temporary_object(0.1);  // Create object
    std::unique(..., temporary_object);
}
// Left nested scope, the `temporary_object` is destructed
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! 
This means, after creating the temporay object (in what you wrote as `std::unique(..., temporary_object);`) the unique-function calls the temporary object multiple times using something like `temporary_object(&a, &b)` which was overloaded by the `bool operator()(...)`